# Unable to install Godaddy SSL on openlitespeed webserver

Tags: ssl-certificate, godaddy, ssl-certificate-errors, litespeed

I'm trying to install Godaddy Ssl to openLitespeed server but it's not working.
I added .key .crt files to /usr/local/lsws/conf/cert/
then added the path to ssl listener as:

$SERVER_ROOT/conf/cert/server.key
$SERVER_ROOT/conf/cert/server.crt
$SERVER_ROOT/conf/cert/ca_bundle.crt

and restart the server but I got this error

```
/usr/local/lsws/conf/cert/server.crt and Key
File:/usr/local/lsws/conf/cert/server.key get SSL error: error:04000093:RSA
routines:OPENSSL_internal_OUT_OF_RANGEerror:04000068:RSA
routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_RSA_PARAMETERS
error:06000066ublic key routines:OPENSSL_internalECODE_ERROR
error:13000068KCS8 routines:OPENSSL_internalECODE_ERROR
error:0900000cEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:ASN.1 encoding routineserror:04000093:RSA
routines:OPENSSL_internal_OUT_OF_RANGE
error:04000068:RSA
routines:
OPENSSL_internal:BAD_RSA_PARAMETERS
error:06000066ublic key
routines:OPENSSL_internalECODE_ERROR
error:13000068KCS8
routines:OPENSSL_internalECODE_ERRORerror:0900000cEM
routines:OPENSSL_internal:ASN.1 encoding routines
error:10000009:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internalEM routines
```

I tried to apply this command to remove password

```
openssl rsa -in forum.key -out forum_no_encrypt.key
```

But also it's still not working but now it gives me different error:

```
[SSL:0x2486d60] 
Config SSL Context with Certificate File:
/usr/local/lsws/conf/cert/server.crt and Key

File:/usr/local/lsws/conf/cert/server.key
get SSL error: error:06000066ublic key
routines:OPENSSL_internalECODE_ERROR
error:0900000cEM
routines:OPENSSL_internal:ASN.1 
encoding routineserror:10000009:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internalEM routines
```

I tried a lot but I couldn't find the solution. If anyone has this experience before please help me.

Thank you

Comment: what's your cert/key format ?  it should like start by `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`  and `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: @qtwrk yes it's starting like this